# Nginx docker reverse proxy with http/https and tcp (ssh)

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I have a docker container with nginx (v. 1.17, **no** plus version) set up as a reverse-proxy (http/https) to other docker containers and machines.

An example configuration I have is the following:

```
server {
    resolver     127.0.0.11;

    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name gitlab.mydomain.com;

    location / {
    proxy_pass http://gitlab:30000;

        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host:$server_port;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

And *this works perfectly*.

**What is missing is the configuration for accessing gitlab (and other machines I need) trough SSH.**

I saw in some other questions that you can use streams and other new nginx features, but I didn't quite get how to embed this with my current configuration.

Can someone help me with this settings? **How can we combine http/https reverse proxy with ssh reverse-proxy?**

Comment: Do you use an OSS version or Nginx plus? Then some configuration may be different. Regardless that you may look for [nginx stream module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/stream/ngx_stream_core_module.html)

Comment: OSS. Sorry, I update the question. I forgot to mention this.